# Read env variable from logback.xml file in order to enable json encoder on Spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am trying to enable a json encoder on my `logback.xml` file which will allow me to log in json based on an environment variable called `JSON_LOGGING`.
If JSON_LOGGING=true then I would like to activate the json encoder, other wise I would like it to be deactivated. I am just not sure how to read exactly the env variable on my logback file. This is what I have so far:

```
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <if condition= MY JSON_LOGGING VARIABLE IS TRUE>
    <then>
      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
    </then>
  <else>
     <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </else>  
</appender>
```

Would anyone know how I could read the `JSON_LOGGING` env var value on my logback file? I am kinda clueless..

Answer (score 0):

Just use your environment variable inside curly braces preceded of a `$` symbol like this: `${JSON_LOGGING}` as the section variable substitution says on the official documentation:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution